# Multiple Inheritance: takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

In testing multiple inheritance, I have the follow Date, Time and DateTime class heirarchy

```
class time:
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time 

    def getTime():
        return self.time;

class date:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def getDate():
        return self.date

class datetime(time,date):
    def __init__(self, input_time, input_date):
        time.__init__(self, input_time)
        date.__init__(self, input_date)
```

Instantiating and checking the date works fine:

```
my_datetime = datetime("12PM","Today")
my_datetime.date
```

> ```
> 'Today'
> ```

But running the getDate function yeilds a parameter error and I don't understand why

```
my_datetime.getDate()
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-17-120ecf58a608> in <module>
> ----> 1 my_datetime.getDate()
>
> TypeError: getDate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
> ```

Comment: Should be `def getDate(self):` since Python internally passes `self` when you call `my_datetime.getDate()`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I had looked at that one before but I hadn't noticed the difference but I saw it looking at it a second time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the multiple inheritance issue. In fact, you'd get exactly the same error trying to call `getDate` on an instance of `date`.

The cause of the issue is that you've forgotten to list `self` as an argument to `getDate` (and `time.getTime` as well). The instance the method gets called on will be passed automatically as the first positional argument, so you need to write the method with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you what is wrong. You've defined `getDate` to accept no parameters. When you do `someObject.someMethod()`, python automatically passes the object instance as the first parameter (almost universally named `self`).

If `getDate` should be called on an instance of the class, you need to define it like this:

```
def getDate(self):
    ...
```